# Spark on Kubernetes: spark-local-dir ERROR: already exists/not unique

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am struggling to understand the Spark documentation in order to set up the local-dir correctly.

### Setup:

I am running Spark 3.1.2 on Kubernetes via the Sparkoperator approach. The Number of executor Pods varying on job size and available resources on the cluster. A typical case is that i start the job with 20 requested executors but 3 Pods remain in pending state and spark complete the job with 17 executors.

### Base Problem:

I am running in the error "The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage." due to much spilling of data into the default local-dir created via `empty-dir`on the kubernetes nodes.

This is a known issue and it should be solved by pointing the `local-dir` to a mounted presistent volume.

I tried to approaches but both are not working:

### Approach 1:

Following the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#local-storage I added the following options into the spark-config

```
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName": "tmp-spark-spill"
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.storageClass": "csi-rbd-sc"
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.sizeLimit": "3000Gi"
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.path": ="/spill-data"
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.readOnly": "false"
```

the full yaml looks like

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: job1
  namespace: spark
spec:
  serviceAccount: spark
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "xxx/spark-py:app-3.1.2"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/work-dir/nfs/06_dwh_core/jobs/job1/main.py
  sparkVersion: "3.0.0"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 0
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 0
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  sparkConf:
    "spark.default.parallelism": "400"
    "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "400"
    "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
    "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields": "1000"
    "spark.ui.port": "4045"
    "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "0" 
    "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "512"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName": "tmp-spark-spill"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.storageClass": "csi-rbd-sc"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.sizeLimit": "3000Gi"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.path": ="/spill-data"
    "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.readOnly": "false"
  driver:
    cores: 1
    memory: "20G"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.2
    serviceAccount: spark
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: /opt/spark/work-dir/nfs
  executor:
    cores: 20
    instances: 20
    memory: "150G"
    labels:
      version: 3.0.0
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: /opt/spark/work-dir/nfs
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      nfs:
        server: xxx
        path: /xxx
        readOnly: false
```

### Issue 1:

this results in an error saying that the pvc already exists and it only creates effectively one executor.

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/spark-poc/persistentvolumeclaims. Message: persistentvolumeclaims "tmp-spark-spill" already exists. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=persistentvolumeclaims, name=tmp-spark-spill, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=persistentvolumeclaims "tmp-spark-spill" already exists, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=AlreadyExists, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

Do I have to define this local-dir claims for every executor? kind of

```
 "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName": "tmp-spark-spill"
.
.
.
 "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-2.options.claimName": "tmp-spark-spill"
.
.
.
 "spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-3.options.claimName": "tmp-spark-spill"
.
.
.
```

But how can I make it dynamicaly if I have changing numbers of executors? Is it not automatically picking it up from the executor config?

### Approach 2:

I created an pvc myself mounted it as volume and set the local-dir as spark config parameter

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-spark-spill
  namespace: spark-poc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3000Gi
  storageClassName: csi-rbd-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

mounted into to executors like

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: job1
  namespace: spark
spec:
  serviceAccount: spark
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "xxx/spark-py:app-3.1.2"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/work-dir/nfs/06_dwh_core/jobs/job1/main.py
  sparkVersion: "3.0.0"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 0
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 0
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  sparkConf:
    "spark.default.parallelism": "400"
    "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "400"
    "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
    "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields": "1000"
    "spark.ui.port": "4045"
    "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "0" 
    "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "512"
    "spark.local.dir": "/spill"
  driver:
    cores: 1
    memory: "20G"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.2
    serviceAccount: spark
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: /opt/spark/work-dir/nfs
  executor:
    cores: 20
    instances: 20
    memory: "150G"
    labels:
      version: 3.0.0
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: /opt/spark/work-dir/nfs
      - name: pvc-spark-spill
        mountPath: /spill
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      nfs:
        server: xxx
        path: /xxx
        readOnly: false
    - name: pvc-spark-spill
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-spark-spill
```

### Issue 2

This approach fails with the message that the `/spill` must be unique.

```
 Message: Pod "job1-driver" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[7].mountPath: Invalid value: "/spill": must be unique.
```

### Summary and Questions

It seems that every executor needs his own pvc or at least his own folder on the pvc to spill his data. But how do I configure it correctly? I am not getting it from the documentation

Thanks for your help
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark should be able to create PVC dynamically by setting up claimName= OnDemand.
Attaching multiple pods for the same pvc will be issue on Kubernetes end

attaching screenshot  for documentation
[image: config screenshot]

You can look into nfs share which will work outside kubenetes manage volumes.
Example
https://www.datamechanics.co/blog-post/apache-spark-3-1-release-spark-on-kubernetes-is-now-ga

Comment: Ok I tried it with this approach. Now I am running into a new problem, that the spark-operator user does not have permission to create pvc. 
```
Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:spark-operator:<my-namespace>-operator" cannot create resource "persistentvolumeclaims" in API group "" in the namespace "<my-namespace>".
```
In the sparkoperator Chart I can't find any role definitions that would allow the verb create to the resource pvc?! Thats weird

Comment: you will need to provide additional permission to your kubernetes service account or use admin account

Comment: So meaning I can't use the helm chart for the Spark Operator like it currently is but have to modify the chart by cloning it or manually alter the role. Ok I will try that and give feedback

Comment: serviceAccount: spark ,This service account must have create in k8 cluster by somebody.This need additional permissions.Help chart remain same otherwise

Comment: Fantastic. Changing the roles for the service account manually on Kubernetes did do the trick. Now the job completed without any issue. Thanks for your help. I open an issue on the spark-operator github page that this should be added to the future spark-operator helm chart